# Custom EntityFramework Core Provider Implementation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to take the [EF Relational Provider Sample](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/master/samples/Miscellaneous/Internals/WritingAProvider) and create a nuget package out of it so I can use it in a test project. The result correctly adds EF Relational but is unable to see my modified extension. For example the DbContextOptions does not show .UseMyRelationalProvider. Is there anywhere else I can find more in depth guides besides what is already on ef.readthedocs.org?

Comment: You could look at the source code of the existing providers.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I have been studying your repo quite a bit. My problem had to do with me not targeting the correct framework. I was able to produce a working mock up.

Comment: If you are just trying to do some unit testing with EF, consider using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory instead. https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/in-memory/

Comment: I was actually hoping to prototype a provider for MS Access but without System.Data.OleDb in .NET Core I am not sure how to proceed.